# curl works in CLI, but not in PHP

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

curl works in CLI, but not in PHP.

The following command works in the command line:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Authorization: Basic [token]" https://api.example.com/v1/token -v -k

* About to connect() to api.example.com port 443 (#0)
..

> POST /v1/token HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: api.example.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Authorization: Basic [token]
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 30 Apr 2021 02:52:24 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 325
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: Express
< ETag: W/"145-rseWkvhNxxhur+O7jUfApznKiww"
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.example.com left intact
{"accesstoken":"token","type":"Bearer","expired":"20210501115224"}
```

And in PHP using the code below:

test.php

```
<?php
$host = 'https://api.example.com/v1/token';

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic [token]'
);

$oCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$response = curl_exec($oCurl);

curl_close($oCurl);
```

$ php test.php

```
* About to connect() to api.example.com port 443 (#0)
..

> POST /v1/token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.example.com
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Basic [token]
Content-Length: -1
Expect: 100-continue

< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: nginx
< Date: Fri, 30 Apr 2021 04:22:08 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 150
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

The result is a HTTP Status code 400 Bad Request. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Please Help.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Content-Length: -1` looks weird.

Comment: @CBroe 
I think so too. 
but I don't know what to do.

Comment: Since you are not sending any body content, it should be 0, if given at all. Have you tried just adding it to your headers, so that cURL doesn’t feel inclined to add it itself?

Comment: @CBroe As you said, I added 'Content-Length: 0' to the header, and it works well!
I spent hours on this problem.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Cool! I added a short answer, based on the previous comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Content-Length: -1` looks weird.

Seems like cURL is adding that automatically, because your request does not contain a POST body - but then it should be set to `0`, if it gets set at all.

Add `'Content-Length: 0'` to your `$headers` array, so that cURL won’t add the header itself with the wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

@choi

did you encode your token?

ej.

```php
$host = 'https://api.example.com/v1/token';

$token = base64_encode('username:Password0..');
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic ' . $token
);

$oCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
...
```

Response

```
$> php curl_test.php
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /v1/token HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6UGFzt3dtcmQwLi4=

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Fri, 30 Apr 2021 06:50:59 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
...
```

Ref: [curl basic auth](https://reqbin.com/req/c-haxm0xgr/curl-basic-auth-example)

Comment: Yes I have encoded it.

In my guess, it seems to be some kind of problem with PHP curl.
Using the guzzle Library, it works fine.